# Access Web service from java when wsdl file is known

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to access a web service in the remote system by using java code. I take the WSDL URL from the XMethods registry and download the WSDL file from that location. I parse the WSDL file and display the list of operations and their Input and Output parameters and type. I will get the Input from the user according to the Information I got from the WSDL file. Now What I am need is I need to display the user the corresponding output from the Webservice. For this what is the easiest method to consume the Webservice. I dont have any Idea. Please anyone can help me??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can user axis2 jar framework to consume the webservice. Axis2 jar's generate the dependency files to consume the web service. Use this link to create client files.
http://javapapers.com/web-service/axis2-web-service-using-eclipse/

Comment: I dont use any IDE for my project. Without using any IDE there is any possibility to call the remote web service.

Comment: compile your project with all jar files and create those stubs and client files manually.

Comment: I find solution here.http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-hello-world-example/ Thank you for your suggestions @Shriram